# How to use bionic-updates?

Tags: apt, package-management, source

I have a dependency problem on 18.04, `libglib2.0-0` is a bit too old (I need `2.56.3` but only `2.56.1-2ubuntu1` is available).

When looking at the [details of the package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libglib2.0-0), I see that

```
Paquet libglib2.0-0
(...)
bionic (18.04LTS) (libs): GLib library of C routines 
2.56.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 [security]: amd64 i386 
2.56.1-2ubuntu1 [ports]: arm64 armhf ppc64el s390x
bionic-updates (libs): GLib library of C routines 
2.56.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el s390x
(...)
```

`bionic-updates` fits the bill. **How can I use it with `apt`?**

I currently have APT sources set by default to

```
deb http://mirror.plusserver.com/ubuntu/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://mirror.plusserver.com/ubuntu/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted universe multiverse
```

Answer (score 2):

It was simply a matter of adding `bionic-updates` to the sources list:

```
deb http://mirror.plusserver.com/ubuntu/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://mirror.plusserver.com/ubuntu/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://mirror.plusserver.com/ubuntu/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://mirror.plusserver.com/ubuntu/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
```