# What is bionic-updates?

Tags: apt, versions

After having had [a tactical issue with `bionic-updates`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1119794/how-to-use-bionic-updates), I came to wonder what `bionic-updates` actually was but could not find any documentation.

What is this distribution for? Is this some kind of "*testing* but not quite" for bionic?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine (eg. the Adding Repositories section) shows -updates is expected, because it may have updated packages since release. If you look up `gcc` in packages (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&keywords=gcc) you'll note bionic-updates contains a later package for Bionic (18.04) than existed in bionic. For some packages there may be none, others may have greater difference.  -proposed is the 'testing' packages.

Comment: Also: [What is the difference between security, updates, proposed and backports in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades?](https://askubuntu.com/q/401941/760903)